# Java Generics: Sort Map by Value

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, sorting

Trying to compile the following function that sorts a generic map I get this error:

```
"The method compareTo(V) is undefined for the type V"
```

Please help to make this work!

```
public class CollectionsPlus<K,V> {

    /**
     * Sort map by value
     * @param map
     * @return
     */
    public static<K,V> Map<K, V> sortMapByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
                map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list,
                new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1,
                            Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
                        return (o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()));
                    }
                });

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<K, V> entry = it.next();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have `V` implement `Comparable`. You can explicitly require it by writing:

```
public static<K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortMapByValue(Map<K, V> map)
```

Alternatively, you can cast `o1.getValue()` and `o2.getValue()` to `Comparable<V>`.

Comment: for best results, use `V extends Comparable<? super V>`

Comment: It is getting more and more cryptic. When Java will have a decent type system? Not in my life-time, I am afraid :)

Comment: @Anton.Ashanin It is not required but gives more flexibility. Imagine that `Cat` is a subclass of `Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`: your method won't be able to sort a `Map<Object, Cat>` by values. If however you declare the method as `V extends Comparable<? super V>`, you can now sort that map by value, because `Cat` implements `Comparable<Animal>` i.e. *`Comparable<Something super Cat>`*.